# Программирование для системы

Tags: linux, c

Вопрос может показаться глупым, но я не столь глуп, как это может показаться. Вот, например, есть такая задача: необходимо сделать, так, чтобы при открытии папки(любой, в Linux например) отображалось окно с приветствием или какой-то другое окно. Вот такая нехитрая задача. Может, её коим образом можно реализовать?

Comment: ИМХО, это даже не внедрялось с целью предотвращения размножения всяких вирусов/троянов. Ближайший аналог - autorun.inf, но и он уже отключен везде и работает только на дисках в Windows. Для web-страниц это можно организовать в виде соответствующей страницы с перечислением содержимого.

Comment: "Открытие папки" — это то? Дабл-клик в файловом менеджере? В каком?

Comment: А что такое "отображалось окно" ? Отображалось где ? Если я зашел удаленно, через терминал, то мне то же на моем клиенте с неизвестной ОС должно окно открыться ? Или на терминале буковками отрисоваться подобие окна ? А что если открытие папки происходит при выполнении автоматического скрипта, индексации для быстрого поиска (который обычно обходит периодически все папки), куда ему окно отображать, если у него средств вывода информации вообще нет

Comment: **необходимо сделать, так, чтобы при открытии папки** - эта задача в Linux решается очень просто: используйте средство ядра inotify. Существует прикладное API (на С), для использования этого средства. В этом API есть событие IN_OPEN, которое Вы можете отслеживать на файле или директории.

"Наблюдение за файловой системой Linux с помощью inotify." 28.12.2010
 Автор: Ian Shields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос.

Вот тут есть пример аудита папки https://www.linux.com/learn/customized-file-monitoring-auditd . Если настроить на какой-то определенный путь, то можно получить события перехода в папку и её просмотр, а также комманду, которая обращается к этой папке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]